# Company Page, who you will work with, job title

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, company-page

I recently added myself to "Who you would work with" on a [company page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/the-washington-post). The issue I have is the job title that is listed for me is not the job title I have for that company. The title is the latest position I added to [my CV](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/epascarello).

It would be nice if either

- You can link the Company Page to the company in your CV so you can pull the correct title
- Or pull the title via the order in the CV and not the last added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch!

Here's the proposed solution - we already allow reordering entries in the experience section using those arrows:

[image]

So let's do this: if there's more than one "current" job in the experience section, we'll now pick the *highest ranked* job for the company page (not the job with the latest start date, as we did in the past).

Check your company page, I think it's showing the correct job now for you.